# How to resolve a set of promises and values using Bluebird

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I have a list values

```
xs = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I also have an asynchronous function `square` that returns a promise of the square of the argument passed to it. I want to pass the elements of my to list to my function in parallel, then collect the promises into an array and wait for them all to complete. I can formulate this as a map/reduce operation.

```
Promise
.map(xs, function(x) {
        return square(x)
    }
)
.reduce(function(ys, y) {
        return ys.concat(y)
    }, [])
```

This eventually returns the resolved values

```
[1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Easy enough. Now say I want to include the original argument in the answer array like so.

```
[{x:1, y:1}, {x:2, y:4}, {x:3, y:9}, {x:4, y:16}]
```

The tricky part is now I have a list of objects, each of which at the beginning of the reduce step has a promise buried in its `y` property. How do I write the Bluebird code to do this reduce step?

Comment: This is tangential, but in your original code you don't really need to do `.map(xs, function(x) { return square(x); })`. `square` is a function, you can just pass it in: `.map(xs, square)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I'd write it, I'm using ES6 code through Babel in my bluebird.

```
import {props, map} from "bluebird";

map(xs, x => props({x, y:square(x)}); // do something with it :)
```

This uses `Promise.props` for waiting for properties of an object.

Answer (score 5):

You wouldn't write this in the `reduce` step. Put it in the `map` step instead:

```
Promise.map(xs, function(x) {
    return f(x).then(function(y) {
        return {x:x, y:y};
    });
})
```

In fact, you wouldn't have any reduce step at all, because `map` does already collect the results in an array.

Of course, you could split this in two and flatten your code by doing

```
Promise.map(xs, f).map(function(y, i) {
    return {x:xs[i], y:y};
})
```

but I don't think that `xs[i]` thing is much better.